Definition of the Fourier coefficients of a measure
I have seen in some literature (e.g. Rudin) the Fourier coefficients of a complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{T}:=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$ to be defined as
\begin{align*}
\widehat{\mu}(n) =\int_\mathbb{T} e^{-int} d\mu(t) \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}. 
\end{align*}
What kind of integral is that formally? I guess it should be equal to $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-int} d\mu(t)$. But I have a problem with both expressions. In the first integral the expression $e^{-int}$ doesn't make a lot of sense if $t \in \mathbb{T}$, whereas in the second integral the expression $d\mu(t)$ is confusing since, formally, $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathbb{T}$, not on $[0,2\pi)$. I would appreciate any help.

There is an identification of the one-dimensional Torus with the additive quotient  $\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$. Then any element $z \in \mathbb{T}$ is identified with $e^{2i \pi t }$ for some $t\in [0,1)$. You can easily reparametrize this by $e^{it}$ for $t\in [0,2)$.

Use the identification $t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$ from @Keen-ameteur's comment to transform one of the $t$'s in the integral to match the type of the other.  The integral as written in the question omits mention of this identification, either because the author takes the identification for granted and assumes the reader will too, or because this abuse of notation was explained earlier in the book.

The measure $\mu$ is the arclength measure on the circle. One way to define it is as follows. Let $m$ be the restriction of the Lebesgue measure to $[0,2\pi)$ and $f : [0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{T}$ the bijection $f(t) = e^{it}$. The measure $\mu$ is the pushforward measure of $m$ along $f$: that is, $\mu(E)= m (f^{-1}(E))$. The change of variables formula lets you pass between $[0,2\pi)$ and $\mathbb{T}$. It says that if $g \in L^1(\mu)$, then
$$ \int_\mathbb{T} g \ d \mu = \int_{[0, 2\pi)} g(e^{it}) \ d m. $$
